# Arrays values not identical (but they are?)

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. They seem to contain at least one identical set of values, but performing    `array_diff()` does not return anything even though I think it should! This should have been just routine code but for some reason it's not liking what I've done.

The weird thing is that `var_dump($queue[0]);` returns `String(167);` and `var_dump($videos[0])` returns `String(168)`.

So clearly, they must be different right?

`echo similar_text($queue[0]), $videos[0]);` returns `167`. What!?

**Note: These are just file names and do not represent the contents of the file.**

**Videos Array**

`Array ( [0] => /var/www/downloads/j2/Dexter Season 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6 + Extras (Early Cuts, Audiobooks etc) DVDRip HDTV TSV/Season 3/Dexter Season 3 Episode 04 - All in the Family.avi )`

**Queue Array**

`Array ( [0] => /var/www/downloads/j2/Dexter Season 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6 + Extras (Early Cuts, Audiobooks etc) DVDRip HDTV TSV/Season 3/Dexter Season 3 Episode 04 - All in the Family.avi [1] => j2 )`

**Outputs**

`$diff = array_intersect($queue,$videos); print_r($diff);` *returns* `Array ( )`

`var_dump($queue[0]);` returns `string(167) "/var/www/downloads/j2/Dexter Season 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6 + Extras (Early Cuts, Audiobooks etc) DVDRip HDTV TSV/Season 3/Dexter Season 3 Episode 04 - All in the Family.avi"`

`var_dump($videos[0]);` 
*returns* `string(168) "/var/www/downloads/j2/Dexter Season 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6 + Extras (Early Cuts, Audiobooks etc) DVDRip HDTV TSV/Season 3/Dexter Season 3 Episode 04 - All in the Family.avi"`

`echo similar_text($queue[0], $videos[0]);` *returns* `167`.

I've put the strings into JavaScript character counts, I've used strlen(), trim() to trim whitespace, I've even manually counted each character individually. What's going on?

Comment: Are you aware of the insanity of PHP type conversions? If not, beware. They are devilishly difficult to identify sometimes.

Comment: One of them might contain a non-printable character. Put them both into a hex editor to examine their full contents.

Comment: have you checked line endings? \n vs \r\n?

Comment: What's `var_dump($videos[0][167])`?

Comment: Copied into hex editor including from first quote to space after last quote inclusive : they are identical. There are no line endings. var_dump($videos[0][167]); returns string(1) "i" BUT $queue[0][167] returns string(0) "" .. hmmm

Comment: @Jimbo `var_dump(trim($videos[0]))` and queues too. What do you see with potential whitespace trimmed?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Sorry I should've mentioned.. I've tried trim() also. They both return 167 and 168 respectively. Will update post to reflect this.

Comment: Actually no hex editor is identical, change 168 to 167 at beginning and put them both in = identical.

Comment: Can you show what happens after running both strings through `var_dump(preg_replace_callback('#.#', function($m) { return '\\x' . dechex(ord($m[0])); }, $input))`? Just to make sure we see the exact same byte sequences as you're testing and character encoding isn't involved.

Comment: @DCoder $queue[0] returns string(668) and $videos[0] returns string(672)- do you require both strings?

Comment: Well yes, that way we can see the actual bytes and see where the difference is. And knowing how you got those two strings would also help (do they come from `readdir`, `glob`, ... ?).

Comment: @DCoder Videos[] is grabbed via a RecursiveDirectoryIterator with a pathinfo_extension == 'avi' check. $queue[] is grabbed from a MySQL DB after being input manually as a string (although later will be inserted via PHP). http://jsfiddle.net/mgaWn/

Comment: I've replaced spaces with `·` in the code to highlight the problem. The first string contains `5,·6·+·Extras`, the second one contains `5,·6··+·Extras` - there's a double space before the + sign. HTML collapses whitespace and that becomes invisible, which is one of the reasons I suggested dumping raw input instead of relying on copy-pasted output.

Comment: [They look the same](http://codepad.org/iaIt6wOj)

Comment: @DCoder Sorted! As well as that, I've figured out that CHAR as the column type allows multiple spaces where as VARCHAR2 was invented to cut down on this extra whitespace. If you submit yours as an answer I'll happily tick it. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After converting both strings to hex-escaped form using

```
var_dump(preg_replace_callback('#.#', function($m) {
  return '\\x' . dechex(ord($m[0]));
}, $input))
```

, the result strings appear like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mgaWn/

Looking at them in that form shows that the first string contains `5,·6·+·Extras`, the second one contains `5,·6··+·Extras` - **there's a double space before the `+` sign**.

HTML collapses whitespace and this difference becomes completely invisible. It is generally a good idea to compare the data as close to its original format as possible, before any output format specifics (such as character encodings or this HTML whitespace minimization) get in your way.

Comment: Brilliant! And just an added extra for those inserting strings into a MySQL DB containing two or more adjacent 'spaces', make sure you're inserting that value NOT into a column with type `VARCHAR`, but into one with the type `CHAR`. Thanks again @DCoder!

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a character that is non-printable.

Write out both strings into a file, from PHP, in binary format, and compare the results with a hex editor or similar. Just copying the strings and then comparing will not do for some cases as it might lose characters.

Comment: This was the beginning to a correct answer, so thanks for that - but DCoder got to the bottom of it first. I'll still give you a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if arrays passed to array_diff() are in right order. Caught myself few times on this.