# Pasted MySQL Select Statement Returns Empty Set, but Manual Select Works Fine

Tags: php, mysql

This one has 2 tech teams baffled.

I have an HTML form that submits to a PHP script that generates the following simple MySQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter='something';
```

The problem is, when I run the PHP script, I get an empty set returned. However, when I type the command into SQL manually, it works fine and returns rows as it should. The closest guess I can figure is, the pasted command has some sort of hidden characters in it ... ?

Any advice is greatly appreciated

EDIT:

> exact PHP query: 
>   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Residential WHERE ".$parameters." ORDER BY 'Residential','list_price' ASC LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$listinglimit."; ") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
>   echo'd query (which is also submitted to MySQL): 
>   SELECT * FROM Residential WHERE sub_area_name='TJ–Trojan' AND list_price <= 99999999 ORDER BY 'Residential','list_price' ASC LIMIT 0, 10; 
>   If I paste that query into phpmyadmin, the result is an empty set. But if I type it manually then the result is returned rows (as it should be)

Comment: Confirm that you are querying the same database in both cases.

Comment: Echo or log the actual generated SQL. It's most likely that something isn't being escaped properly.

Comment: Check the Apache 'error.log'. (usualy '/var/log/apache2/error.log')

Comment: Is `'something'` a constant string, or is it generated from user input? What API are you using (`mysql_query`, mysqli, PDO)? Are you checking for errors, or just assuming the query was executed successfully and returned zero rows?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. I can tell you: same database and table, error log has nothing, echo statements look *exactly* the same, "something" is generated from HTML input, and API is mysql_query.

Comment: Post the PHP code you are using (not just the `mysql_query()` call, but the context as well - how you are building the query string, how you are collecting the results...). Also, see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12515013/1233508) is of any help, specifically, if converting the query string to that hex format shows anything interesting.

Comment: check if something has any whitespace. easy to miss,and it can make a difference.

Comment: again, cant use regular single quote for column name (or table name), that is only for variables.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming you have inside your code something like

```
...
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter='$param'";
...
```

Just echo out the var $query to make sure it's indeed the same as the one you ran manually

```
echo $query;
```

In my opinion if it's the same, it can't fail just because it's executed via php.

Comment: yup, that's what I have and did. query is i.e. SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter='$param' ... echo'd query is SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter='something'. When I copy/paste the echo'd query I get empty set. When I type it word-for-word manually, it works.

Comment: Also double check what quotes you use. "SELECT .... $param" is not the same as 'SELECT .... $param'. And ' is not the same as `.

Comment: That's strange. Try using [this](https://defuse.ca/checksums.htm) to see if there's actually a difference between the two strings (the manual typed one and the copied one)

Comment: I KNEW it! The checksums are different! So, the million dollar question ... how do I identify and/or strip out whatever non-printing junk is in the query?

Comment: change your query to:
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Residential WHERE ".$parameters." ORDER BY 'Residential', 'list_price' ASC LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$listinglimit) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: As suggested by Traian, I tried removing the "; " from the end but unfortunately got the same (empty set) result...

Comment: Try [this](http://www.text-compare.com/). Maybe it will highlight the differences.

Comment: Traian, it highlighted the hyphen/dash in 'TJ-Trojan'. When I try using &#045; in place of the hyphen/dash in the HTML form, the result is the same (empty set)

Comment: The dash you are using is [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (&#8211; not &#045;)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I can't thank everyone enough for the speedy and helpful replies. The problem was in the HTML code. For some reason, the "-" in the HTML was not the same as the "-" in the MySQL table (even though they look identical). I re-coded the HTML by deleting/replacing every occurrence of the dash and everything works!