# PHP & SQL: Can the same statement return different resultsets by the fact whether it where send by a php script or was send directly via a .sql file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, resultset

I tried to create a .php which should send a statement to my local MySQL. The connection works fine and the statement is successfully run but returns NULL. When executing the statement via cmd itreturns the right resultset.

**Is there the possibility of the same statement returning different resultsets determined by the fact wheather it was sent by a php script or were executed directly via a .sql file**?

Cheers,

Uno

Comment: Did you check for errors after executing the statement?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: No. The query always runs on MySQL server at the end no matter what triggers the query.

Comment: There are cases where result sets are nondeterministic, or e.g. where a configuration setting is invoked when you connect via command line which could change the behavior of the database, but my money is on your php being the issue.  Again, please provide some code, especially the php that builds your query, fetches it, and outputs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your quick answers and comments. I was able to solve the issue in the meantime.
**It's similar to:

[Pasted MySQL Select Statement Returns Empty Set, but Manual Select Works Fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637956/pasted-mysql-select-statement-returns-empty-set-but-manual-select-works-fine)

but was about MySQL expecting Latin1 typeset and HTML sending Unicode strings.

utf8_decode() was the key to success:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php**

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Question:
Does anyone know why MySQL just ignores UTF-8 Strings instead of returning something like 'bla bla latin1 coded String expected bla bla'?

Answer (score 0):

If the query is the same in the .php file as was in the.sql file then they would match. It should not return different resultsets since it is the same query. It sounds like a formatting issue related to something as simple as quotation marks. If you copied and pasted the code across files then that would be your issue.

There isn't much to go by unless we can see your code